# Facebook Access Token lost after App Restart

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working with Facebook SDK 4.0 and using the in-built LoginButton.
I have a `Fragment` which contains the LoginButton and another which just contains a TextBox.

Here's a code snippet from the `Fragment` :

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private OnLoginFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged in successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLoginEvent(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLoginEvent(false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to log in. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLoginEvent(false);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onLoginEvent(boolean loginSuccess) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onLoginFragmentInteraction(loginSuccess);
    }
}

public interface OnLoginFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onLoginFragmentInteraction(boolean onLoginSuccess);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

The Activity looks something like this :

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    LoginFragment.OnLoginFragmentInteractionListener, TestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

private LoginFragment loginFragment;
private TestFragment testFragment;
private AccessToken accessToken;
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private Profile fbProfile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        Log.d(TAG, "Bundle = null, isLoggedIn() = " + isLoggedIn());
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            testFragment = new TestFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, testFragment).commit();
        } else {
            loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment).commit();
        }
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (frag instanceof LoginFragment) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bundle != null, fragment = LoginFragment");
            loginFragment = (LoginFragment) frag;
        }
        else if (frag instanceof TestFragment) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bundle != null, fragment = TestFragment");
            testFragment = (TestFragment) frag;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onLoginFragmentInteraction(boolean loginSuccess) {
    updateUI(loginSuccess);
}

public void updateUI(boolean loggedIn) {
    // User is logged in, show the main fragment
    if (loggedIn) {
        testFragment = new TestFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, testFragment).commit();
    }
    // User is logged out, show the login fragment
    else {
        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment).commit();
    }
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

What I want to do is to check if the user has already logged in. If they have, then I show the Test Fragment, otherwise I show the Login Fragment.

So when the user first logs in, I use the interface callback to notify the Activity that the user has logged in and show the TestFragment. Also, if the user goes away from the app and then returns, I check in the `onCreate()` method if the user is logged in by checking the access token.

When the user first logs in, it works as desired.
But the problem I'm facing is that if I kill the app or remove it from the Recents list, I lose the access token. `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` always returns null.
Is this not the right way to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention in your comment. You have should checked user logged in when the FacebookSDK finished initialization.
The problem in your case is that you checked AccessToken when the SDK had not finished initialization yet. To solve this problem checking AcessToken in onInitialized() method of FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback which is called when the SDK has been initialized.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onInitialized() {
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            ..............
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please try to answer the whole question. What about "But the problem I'm facing is that if I kill the app or remove it from the Recents list, I lose the access token." ?

Comment: I have tested and even I restart the emulator and this code did work. Did you try this?

Comment: I think it's good that you tested your solution. Much better than the "try this" variety :) Having said that, I see that you introduced a callback where there wasn't one before. My problem remains: the link from user2558050 is more like the original "problem code" (no callback), so if you could explain your solution in addition to posting a code snippet, then people like me (never did anything with facebook SDK yet) would understand better why they can do it your way.

Comment: In the comment of @user2558050 in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30288238/5460059. You can see the FacebookSDK saves and sets AccessToken and Profile during initialization. The problem in this case is that he checked AccessToken when the SDK had not finished initialization yet. To solve this problem checking AcessToken in onInitialized() method of FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback which is called when the SDK has been initialized.

Comment: Additionally if you're using the newer version of the login module (initialization is implicit on app start) and checking for login in something like a splash page, you might want to delay checking if the Access Token is valid by a couple of hundred milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

When the login is successful save access token somewhere. To the database or to the shared preferences. When your app starts check if there is an access token and if is valid.

Comment: According to the official documentation : 


"The FacebookSDK saves this data in shared preferences and sets it during SDK initialization. You can see if a person is already logged in by checking AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()."


https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#access_profile

So shouldn't it be handled automatically?